# source of errors in simulation

Tags: simulation, software

Other than operator errors, machine errors, and rounding, what might cause standard circuit simulators to produce bad results? In other words, are there known circuits for which simulation is "risky"?

Thanks much in advance
Joe

Comment: Why was this closed?

Comment: I agree with Chris Laplante -- I suspect a relatively small set of circuits is known to be difficult or impossible to simulate. Why was this closed?

Comment: I don't know of any simulator that correctly simulates ["Opposite-polarity voltage generator by hole impact ionization in a silicon bipolar transistor"](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=192771), aka [US patent 5235216](https://www.google.com/patents/US5235216) (1993).

Answer (score 0):

Generally oscillators are hard to simulate.  Unless you get the step size right and the transient simulation length correct it's very common to not see oscillators oscillate.